# How long does sealing a driveway take?

Tags: sealing, driveway, asphalt

I've found a number of videos and how-to guides online, but they're all lacking an answer to this basic question: how much time should I budget to do it?  The repair work (filling cracks and holes) I'm not so worried about, as that time can be spread over a few days, but for the actual application I get the impression that it's best to do that all at once.

I found an estimate of "1 or 2 hours for an average size driveway", but "average" is a pretty ambiguous term.  My driveway is approx. 2500 ft^2, an average driveway might be 400 ft^2 (*???*), so should I plan on 6-8 hours with 2 people working on it?

Comment: As it turns out, the answer is "about 10 minutes", because we decided that it would take too long to do ourselves and hired someone to do it.

Comment: What kind of company does stuff like this? A general concrete/driveway place?

Comment: @MikeCole - you can google for  `seal coat` and the name of your town.  There are crews that specialize in this.

Answer (score 1):

6-8 hours with 2 people sounds like it'd be about right to me, but I don't have experience in such things.  2500 ft^2 would definitely be above average in my book, that is like 10 ft wide by 250 ft long. I'd expect that a normal drive way would be 15-20 feet long.